# ESLint broken: Rules with suggestions must set the `meta.hasSuggestions` property to `true`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, eslintrc

I am using VSCode, and when I add the line `'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn'` to my .eslintrc.js, I get the following in the ESLint output:

```
Rules with suggestions must set the `meta.hasSuggestions` property to `true`. Occurred while linting
C:\Users\filepath.jsx:72 Rule: "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"
```

This breaks all other linting. I've tried adding the following to my .eslintrc.js:

```
meta: {
    hasSuggestions: true
},
```

which gives me the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.js is invalid:
    - Unexpected top-level property "meta".
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended', 'plugin:react-hooks/recommended'],
    settings: {
        'react': {
            'version': 'detect'
        }
    },
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 13,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['react-hooks', 'react'],
    rules: {
        'react/prop-types': [0],
        quotes: ['error', 'single'],
        semi: [1],
        'react/jsx-indent': [1],
        'no-multi-spaces': [1],
        'indent': [2],
        'react/jsx-newline': [2, { prevent: true }],
        'no-trailing-spaces': [1],
        'no-multiple-empty-lines': [1, { max: 1 }],
        'space-infix-ops': [1],
        'object-curly-spacing': [1, 'always'],
        'comma-spacing': [1],
        'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
        'react/self-closing-comp': 1,
        'react/jsx-closing-tag-location': 1,
        'no-unreachable': 1,
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn'
    },
};
```

Here's is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.1.4-1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.1.4-1",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.1.4-1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-on-rails": "12.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.53.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "./node_modules/@rails/webpacker/package/babel/preset.js"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: how you solved the issue none of the solution is working for me

Comment: @Sagar I solved this using the accepted answer below

Answer (score 58, accepted):

ESLint 8.0.0 comes with a [breaking change for rules that provide suggestions](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/migrate-to-8.0.0#suggestions). There is nothing you can put into your .eslintrc.js to make it work if you use rules that haven't been updated to work after this change.

What you can do:

- Use ESLint 7 until the plugin is updated to work with ESLint 8.
- In case of `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, the offending rule has already been updated (check [this line on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0c0d1ddae4be922f800705ae686fbb887184b38b/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js#L22)), it's just that there hasn't been a stable release of the package since. However there have been daily alpha releases, at the time of writing the latest version is `4.2.1-alpha-c3a19e5af-20211014`. If you really need both ESLint 8 and this plugin, you can use an alpha version until the next stable version comes out.

Comment: React issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22545

Comment: `npm install -D eslint-plugin-react-hooks@next` would work at the moment.

Comment: @next worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Fixed in 4.3.0.

Comment: Nothing is working Rules with suggestions must set the `meta.hasSuggestions` property to `true`. `meta.docs.suggestion` is `ignored by ESLint`.

Comment: Upgrading the npm package that provided the rule fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove the rule `"react/require-default-props": "off",` to get rid of the problem. Not a complete fix but it worked for now with react v18

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error after bumping react-scripts from 4.x to 5.0.1. Since we also had the "eslint-config-react-app" in our package.json, the fix was to also bump this to current. 7.0.1 in our case. Hope this helps I you come across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `eslint-config-react-app` npm package from 5.2.1 to 6.0.0 worked for me!